# Ставятся ли в этом предложении какие-нибудь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

> Хотя по какой-то причине в тоже время мне стало труднее ладить с
>   другими девочками…

Нужно ли обособить "по какой-то причине", или после "хотя", или тут и так всё нормально без запятых?

Comment: "в **то же** время", раздельно пишется. По запятой, не могу ничем подтвердить, но я бы поставил запятую, только если б подразумевал паузу после "причине". Если все произносится на одном дыхании, то запятая не нужна.

Comment: Для этого вопроса больше подходит для [Русский язык SE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Этот сайт для иностранных изучающих. Используйте http://rus.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет причин выделять что‐либо запятыми. Вот примеры из корпуса русского языка

> Например, многие живут с уверенностью, что должны быть безупречными, сильными, умными, и, когда по какой-то причине не могут соответствовать собственным требованиям, расстраиваются, а то и вовсе впадают в депрессию. [Юлия Кожева. Откровенные уроки, способные изменить мир.
>
> Если же человек по какой-то причине слышит эти голоса все время, его или объявляют шизофреником и изолируют от нормальных людей, или назначают пророком и сажают в золотую колесницу. [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]

Обособляются предложные обороты, которые содержат объяснение того, о чем говорится в предложении, и выделяются интонационно: ...Детям, по причине малолетства, не определили никаких должностей, что, впрочем, нисколько не помешало им совершенно облениться… И. Тургенев, Малиновая вода.

Те, что стоят между подлежащим и сказуемым, а не в начале предложения и в конце могут обособляться и нет --авторское решение.

Comment: В то же время пишется отдельно